# Dictionary world replace in Android using HashMap

Tags: android, regex, dictionary

I want to create dictionary using HashMap.

***My JSON which i use to convert to HashMap:***

```
"ok": 'około ',
"g": 'gram ',
"G": 'gram ',
"gr": 'gram ',
"dkg": 'dekagram ',
"dag": 'dekagram ',
"kg": 'kilogram ',
"Szkl": 'szklanka ',
"sz": 'szklanka ',
"Mil": 'mililitr ',
"ml": 'mililitr ',
"l": 'litr ',
"szt": 'sztuk '
```

***Currently I am using this:***

```
val patternString = "(" + join("|", wordsToReplace.keys) + ")"
val pattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString)
val matcher: Matcher = pattern.matcher(description)

val sb = StringBuffer()
while (matcher.find()) {
    val group = matcher.group(1)
    if (wordsToReplace.containsValue(group)) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, wordsToReplace.getValue(group))
    }
}
matcher.appendTail(sb)
return sb.toString()
```

But i need to add additional regex with this conditions:

- number before replaced word
- space before replaced word and space after replaced word (ex. " l ")
- dot with space (". ") or new line after replaced word

Examples:

- "1l" - 1litr
- " l " - litr
- "1l." - 1litr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are dynamically generating the pattern, you can either allow for all permutations and specify whitespace boundaries on the left and right:

```
(?<!\S)(?:\d+| )?(?:ok|g|G|gr|dkg|dag|kg|Szkl|sz|Mil|ml|l|szt)[.\n ]?(?!\S)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBM5mK/1).

If you want to get every specific scenario, you can create an alteration `|` listing all the options which can get quite long.

```
(?<!\S)(?:(?:ok|g|G|gr|dkg|dag|kg|Szkl|sz|Mil|ml|l|szt)|\d+(?:ok|g|G|gr|dkg|dag|kg|Szkl|sz|Mil|ml|l|szt)\.?| (?:ok|g|G|gr|dkg|dag|kg|Szkl|sz|Mil|ml|l|szt) )(?!\S)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ETuREU/1).